# Ajax Javascript: Link doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sharepoint

on a Sharepoint site, I have a navigation that contains `return AjaxNavigate$OnClickHook(event, this);`.
There is also a "normale" `<a href="...">`-tag for the link.

Now, the linked content is being changed by adding a picture inside the link tag.

The picture is shown on the right position, the cursor also shows a link which can be opened via the right-click context menu and chosing "Open Link" or "Open Link in new Tab".
But it does not open when clicked "normally".

I guess that the Ajax code above prevents the normal link handling.
How can I get the image also to be linked correctly?

Thanks.

***edit:***
relevant HTML (generated mostly by a Sharepoint site):

```html
(...)

<div 
  class="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" 
  id="DeltaTopNavigation" 
  role="navigation"
  >

  <div 
    class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox" 
    id="zz13_TopNavigationMenu" 
    onclick="return AjaxNavigate$OnClickHook(event, this);"
    >
    <ul 
      class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" 
      id="zz14_RootAspMenu"
      >
      <li class="static selected">
        <a 
          tabindex="0" 
          class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-bold ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" 
          accesskey="1" 
          href="https://xxx/sites/00001/SitePages/SomeSite.aspx"
          >
          <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
            <span 
              class="menu-item-text" 
              style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; position: relative;"
              >
              <img 
                style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" 
                src="/sites/00001/SiteAssets/images/pic.png" 
                border="0"
                >
              <br>Text
            </span>
            <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
        <a 
          tabindex="0" 
          class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" 
          href="https://xxx/sites/00001/SitePages/SomeSite2.aspx"
          >
          <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
            <span 
              class="menu-item-text" 
              style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; position: relative;"
              >
              <img 
                style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" 
                src="/sites/00001/SiteAssets/images/pic2.png" 
                border="0"
                >
              <br>Text 2
            </span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

(...)
```

***EDIT 2:***
The `<img...`-tag is inserted afterwards, via this code:

```js
 $('[id$="RootAspMenu"]').find('.menu-item-text').each(function(i,item)
  {
   var iconName = "pic_";
   iconName += $(item).text().replace(" ","").toLowerCase();
   iconName += ".png";
   $(this).prepend('<img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="/sites/00001/SiteAssets/images/'+iconName+'" border="0"><br/>');
 
   $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
   $(this).css("position", "relative");
   $(this).css("text-align", "center");
  }
 );
```

...and I noticed that the area "behind" the image (so, the `<span>` area?) is linked correctly. Only the image is not.

Could it be a problem for the link that the image has been inserted afterwards? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show us the whole relevant JS and HTML code in question. For example, where is that `return AjaxNavi...` code located?

Comment: If possible, I'd like to achieve this by editing the inserted image-tag (due to complex access to the Sharepoint scripts)

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: There's a lot of classes and fluff code, I tried to format it to make it easier to read.  Note: sometimes adding whitespace between elements have undesired effects.  Above, I put the `<img>` on new lines, remember this in case you need to revert it back.

Comment: So what do you want to happen on click? The AJAX-ish code (whatever it does) or do you want the browser to follow the link?

Comment: I want it to follow the link. I already tried this: `$("div[id*='TopNavigationMenu']").removeAttr("onclick")` but no efffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself!

Inserting in the script/jquery where I insert the image, I also put this:

```js
if ($(this).parent().is("span") ) {
  $(this).unwrap();
}
```

...takes away the `<span>` around the image / inside the link. Now it works correctly!